# How can I work with swagger yaml file in PhpStorm?

Tags: swagger, phpstorm

Working with swagger project (openapi: 3.0.0 ) at app.swaggerhub.com 
I edit data in yaml format and that raised a questions if there is a way 
to work with swagger defintions In PhpStorm 2019.2.3, as it's editor is much better ?

Or some other way more convinient of app.swaggerhub.com ?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "more convenient"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an OpenAPI editor plugin for IntelliJ IDEs:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12887-openapi-editor